# Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory::create(): Argument #3 ($options) must be of type array, null given

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, symfony5.4

I am making a multi step form with the craue/formflow bundle in symfony. I want to pass submitted data to the next form. When I want to render the form it gives me this error

```php
Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory::create(): Argument #3 ($options) must be of type array, null given, called in C:\Users\Armand MBOULE\Documents\Campus_Stage\vendor\craue\formflow-bundle\Form\FormFlow.php on line 970
```

This is my getFormoptions in my flow class

```php
 public function getFormOptions($step, array $options = [])
    {
        $options = parent::getFormOptions($step, $options);

        $formData = $this->getFormData();

        if ($step === 1) {
            
            $options['dateDebut'] = $formData->getDateDebut();
            $options['dateFin'] = $formData->getDateFin();
        }
    }
```

This is my controller

```php
 #[Route('/create/bordereau', name: 'app_bordereau_create', methods: ['GET','POST'])]
    public function createBordereauAction(Request $request, CreateBordereauFlow $flow, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $formBordereau = new Bordereau();

        $flow->bind($formBordereau);

        $form = $submittedForm = $flow->createForm();

        if ($flow->isValid($submittedForm)) {
            $flow->saveCurrentStepData($submittedForm);

            if ($flow->nextStep()) {
                $form = $flow->createForm();
                $flow->saveCurrentStepData($submittedForm);
            } else {
                
            }
            // $em->flush();

            $flow->reset();
        }

        return $this->render('bordereau/create_bordereau.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'flow' => $flow
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: As error state, your `getFormoptions` function is getting `NULL` value for `$options` which is supposed to be an array.